# How to get nyc coverage to work with es6 import (.mjs files)

Tags: javascript, node.js, code-coverage, es6-modules, nyc

I've typically used [nyc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc) to provide coverage for my unit tests.  All honkey dorey for pre-ES6 `require('myModule')` tests.  I'm having trouble getting it to work with unit tests that use ES6 import.  Tests *without coverage* work with `--experimental-modules` and .mjs files:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node --experimental-modules ./test/test.mjs",
    ... others deleted to save space
},
```

And everything works.  I'm using [Tape](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tape) for testing if that matters.  Output looks like:

```
(node:9360) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
TAP version 13
# number
ok 1 should be equal
(... more deleted)
```

But when I try to use nyc, e.g. `nyc --reporter=lcov --extension .mjs npm test`

I get an error:

```
(node:7304) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
Error [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension: C:/Users/Morgan/.node-spawn-wrap-6952-61a26e1bb867/node
    at exports.resolve (internal/loader/ModuleRequest.js:126:13)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/loader/Loader.js:48:40)
    ....
```

I'm using node version 8.9.1 and nyc version 13.0.1, running on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

As [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc#support-for-alternate-file-extensions-jsx-mjs) states, .mjs support should be explicitly added:

> Supporting file extensions can be configured through either the
>   configuration arguments or with the nyc config section in package.json.

```
nyc --extension .mjs npm test
```

---

```
{
  "nyc": {
    "extension": [
      ".mjs"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: As in my question, I'm doing this.  (Both on command line and in the package.json). Is there some other flag I need to set?

Comment: It seems that there are still problems with mjs support. I suppose your best bet is to transpile native modules for coverage, e.g. https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/708#issuecomment-349210734

Comment: Seems like there is no plan to support ECMAScript Modules as this [issue](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/843) has been labeled with the tag `wontfix` unfortunately.